# Collect_set With Case in Hive

Tags: arrays, hive, hiveql

Is there any way to Rewrite below case Statement so Instead of writing Collect_set[0] 4 times ,I can get the same result using single Collect_set.

```
    select id,collect_set(name)[0] as name,sum(salary),
    cASE WHEN month(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(collect_set(date1)[0], 'dd-MM-yyyy')))) 
    IN (01,02,03) THEN 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(collect_set(date1)[0], 'dd-MM-yyyy'))))-1,'-'),
    substr(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(collect_set(date1)[0], 'dd-MM-yyyy')))),3,4))
     ELSE CONCAT(CONCAT(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(collect_set(date1)[0], 'dd-MM-yyyy')))),'-'),
    SUBSTR(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(collect_set(date1)[0], 'dd-MM-yyyy'))))+1,3,4)) 
     END as fy from testing_1.collect_set_test group by id;
```

I am Writing Below Query.

```
select collect_set(CASE WHEN month(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date1), 'dd-MM-yyyy'))) 
IN (01,02,03) THEN CONCAT(CONCAT(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date1), 'dd-MM-yyyy')))-1,'-'),
substr(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date1), 'dd-MM-yyyy'))),3,4)) 
ELSE
 CONCAT(CONCAT(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date1), 'dd-MM-yyyy'))),'-'),
 SUBSTR(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date1), 'dd-MM-yyyy')))+1,3,4))) [0]
 END as fy from testing_1.collect_set_test group by id;
```

But its Giving Below Error.

```
    FAILED: ParseException line 1:446 missing KW_END at ')' near ']' in selection target
    line 1:452 cannot recognize input near 'END' 'as' 'fy' in selection target
```

Can someone please guide me how should i rewrite the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move all aggregation with group and date transformation by into subquery, calculate fy in the upper subquery:

```
select id, name, salary,
    cASE WHEN month(date1) 
               IN (01,02,03) THEN CONCAT(CONCAT(year(date1))-1,'-'),
                              substr(year(date1),3,4))
         ELSE CONCAT(CONCAT(year(date1),'-'),
              SUBSTR(year(date1)+1,3,4)) 
     END as fy 
     from 
          (select to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(collect_set(date1)[0], 'dd-MM-yyyy'))) as date1, 
                  collect_set(name)[0]  as name, 
                  sum(salary) as salary, 
                  id 
            from testing_1.collect_set_test group by id) s
 ;
```

Comment: Hi @leftjoin Yes ,through sub-queries I have tried,but its taking more time with my Complete data, so i was trying without using sub-queries and without multiple Collect_set

Comment: @Varun Why are you using collect_set? I do not see any sorting before collect_set in you query and it seems collect_set(date1)[0] can pick any date from group

Comment: Yes ...It can Pick any date...I just want to ignore date1 column from group by,so had to keep it in collect_set

Comment: @Varun  then use max(date) or min() along with your sum() aggregation in the same gropby, optimizer will do max() only one time. It will work faster than collect_set

Comment: select id,collect_set(name)[0] as name,max(date1),sum(salary),CASE WHEN month(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date1), 'dd-MM-yyyy'))) IN (01,02,03) THEN CONCAT(CONCAT(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date1), 'dd-MM-yyyy')))-1,'-'),substr(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date1), 'dd-MM-yyyy'))),3,4)) ELSE CONCAT(CONCAT(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date1), 'dd-MM-yyyy'))),'-'),SUBSTR(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date1)[0], 'dd-MM-yyyy')))+1,3,4)) end  as fy from testing_1.collect_set_test group by id;

Comment: @ leftjoin tried above query also. but still no luck.its showing date1 is not in group by

Comment: @Varun  because you have to wrap in max() all instances of date1. And in your code there are unix_timestamp(date1), use unix_timestamp(max(date1))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229155/discussion-between-varun-and-leftjoin).